# how to include js file in html which is in different folder

Tags: node.js

I include following socket js file in my html  to communicate on the server

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and i write my connection code in user.js file

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect',()=>
{
    console.log('connected to the server');
});


socket.on('disconnect',()=>
{
    console.log('disconnected to the server');
});
```

and i include it in my html page using

```
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="../routes/users.js"></script>
```

but it said GET http://localhost:3000/routes/users.js  faild

Answer (score 0):

You will have to serve static files from node to get access to it.

There are many libraries that do the same, Express is most used.

In express you can do it like,

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../routes')));
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000, () => console.log(`API running on localhost: ` + 3000));
```

above use of static, will give access to every file that is in routes folder.